# how to trigger kendo-ui e.action from custom button

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to trigger the built in kendo-ui grid "add" action to this custom button in my template. only examples i can find are triggering custom functions. thanks

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <label>Mock Text:</label>
                <a class="k-button"  onclick="trigger dataSource.change.add">Add Product</a>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event for that button with jQuery, you can select it either by ID or its class and call `addRow` method of grid.

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
    grid.addRow();
});
```